# How to decrypt an encrypted RSA key .pem file with Node.js

Tags: node.js, ssl, encryption, rsa, private-key

I have an encrypted private key file (I also have the unencrypted one for comparison), assume that I have the password and I want the decrypted version of that file - I tried using the URSA module (npm install ursa) , but it is not suitable for my needs because it is not portable enough (requires a specific version of the .NET framework on Windows). I need a raw Node.js solution - Is there a module that would let me do this?

If not, what is the exact process for turning this encrypted key into a plain key?
I tried using Node.js' crypto module crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, password)... Using 'DES-EDE3-CBC' as the algorithm and my password, but I get giberrish output which doesn't match the unencrypted version of the key. I was running the decryption on the content starting with o5IM... and ending with ==... I also tried only the string from o5IM to OZDug and that didn't work either.

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,0DC77650897F6756
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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----